# Tkinter button does not appear, sorry guys I know that a thread already exists

Tags: python, tkinter

The button it does not appear , any tips guys?. The screenshot func works fine but not the button, I **have** to close it on my own.

```
import time
from tkinter import *
import pyautogui

class App:

    def __init__(self, master, task):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.button = Button(
            frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=frame.quit
            )
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)
        frame.after(0,task)

def task():
    i = 1
    while i > 0:
        myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
        myScreenshot.save(r"C:\Users\elsin\Desktop\python\nameTask" + str(i) + ".png")
        time.sleep(2)
        i += 1

root = Tk()

app = App(root,task())
root.mainloop()
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\elsin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/elsin/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elsin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\1.py", line 28, in <module>
    app = App(root,task())
  File "C:\Users\elsin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\1.py", line 23, in task
    time.sleep(2)
KeyboardInterrupt

Process finished with exit code -1073741510 (0xC000013A: interrupted by Ctrl+C)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `app = App(root,task)`?

Comment: that doesnt make a difference,its the same task and task(), no parameters so...

Comment: No, with `()` you call the function. Either way, `time.sleep` in the same thread as tkinter will freeze tkinter mainloop and the GUI

Comment: sorry but i didnt understand do i put the TIME command at the of the class?and its ok

Comment: Its never okay to have it in the same thread

Comment: at this moment your code works as `result = task()` and `app = App(root, result)` - so your `task()` is executed at start and it blocks rest of code. You have to use funcition's name `task` without `()` and it will later use `()` to run it. But I see other problem. You use `while`-loop which will block `mainloop()` and `tkinter` will freeze. You would have to run `task` in separated thread, or you have to use `root.update()` in `while`-loop to force `mainloop` to run own loop. OR you should use `root.after()` instead of `while`-loop.

Answer (score 1):

First: you have to send function's name without `()`.

At this moment you have something like

```
result = task()

app = App(root, result)
```

but `task()` runs `while`-loop which runs all time and code never goes to line `App(root, result)` - so it can't display it.

If you send function's name then you will have another problem - your `frame.after(0, task)` starts this task at once and it blocks rest of code.

If you use some delay `frame.after(100, task)` then it will have time to display window with button.

But it still have problem with `task` which runs `while`-loop and it blocks  mainloop`and`tkinter` is freezed.

---

The main problem is that you have two loops which have to work at the same time:

- first: `mainloop()`,
- second: `while`-loop

and this need to run one of them in separated thread, or you have to use `root.after(2000, task)` instead of `while`+`sleep()`

BTW: you should use `master.destroy` instead of `frame.quit` to stop tkinter program

```
import time
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import pyautogui

class App:

    def __init__(self, master, task):

        frame = tk.Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.button = tk.Button(frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=master.destroy)
        self.button.pack(side='left')
        
        frame.after(100, task, 1)

def task(i):
    myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    myScreenshot.save(r"C:\Users\elsin\Desktop\python\nameTask" + str(i) + ".png")
    i += 1
    root.after(2000, task, i)

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root, task)
root.mainloop()
```